# EF Lazy Load Collection

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am trying to get my head around EF.

I have this entity

```
 public class Project : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public int ProjectTypeId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int ProjectStatusId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WorkItem> WorkItems { get; set; }
    public ProjectType ProjectType { get; set; }
    public ProjectStatus ProjectStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I want the collection "WorkItems" to be lazy loaded but project type and project status should be loaded up front.

My question is how do I set this up and how can I see that It's lazy loading or loading it up front without installing sql profiler.

N.B I have set lazy loading false for serialization reasons

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have context that looks something like:

```
public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

You could then call:

```
MyContext db = new MyContext();
db.Projects.Include(x => x.ProjectType).Include(y => y.ProjectStatus).Where...
```

This should eager load ProjectType and ProjectStatus but not WorkItems. You can confirm what EF is doing behind the scene by taking log output to your debug window:

```
db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

Do not forget to put using System.Data.Entity; otherwise you will not be able to use lambda expressions in your include.

If you want to make sure that users of your data layer have ProjectType and ProjectStatus always loaded, you may consider implementing your own repository instead of DbSet.

Hope this helps.